# I can't Download or Upload on Browsers even though connection is fine

Tags: networking, network-interface, internet, download

I can watch videos on youtube stream and even join meetings on Teams for hours with no internet connection issues. But when it comes to downloads and uploads it just fails after a minute, on chrome and other browsers. Uploading anything to Dropbox is impossible, uploading a video on Youtube actually works but it takes an enormous amount of time to upload a short. The message is usually "Failed download/upload check your internet connection".

When i use aria2c it downloads with no problems, idk if it's just smart enough to resume the download when something breaks or it has a solution for me.

[image]

Idk if this is a linux problem or a hardware problem, I would appreciate any guidance.